# How to access custom Layout Slides through VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

If I try to access custom layout slides, VBA error appears

Following code shows error:

`layout = ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(1)`

How should I access custom layout slides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Presentation object has a Designs collection (each Design is what we would have called a SmartMaster before).

Each Design has a SmartMaster and the SmartMaster has a CustomLayouts collection that contains the layouts.  So:

```
Debug.Print ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(1).Name
```

That'll show you the name of the first layout (usually Title Slide) in the first master of the presentation.

Comment: Just to confirm following: each design has SmartMaster or SlideMaster?

Comment: Yes.  Each design has a SlideMaster.  Each SlideMaster has one or more CustomLayouts.  Here's a slightly more detailed explanation I wrote about the differences between versions of PPT and how layouts and such work:  Slides, Masters, Designs, Layouts ... how do they all fit together?
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00989_Slides-_Masters-_Designs-_Layouts_---_how_do_they_all_fit_together-.htm