# Extract master slides used in a presentation to PNG using VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to extract Master slides used in a presentation to PNG.
However, I'm struggling to reference the slide so I can extract it.

The best I have right now is

```
...
' Extract background images
For Each Slide In ActivePresentation.Slides
  ' what is the reference for the master layout
  MsgBox "slide layout =  " & Slide.Layout
    
  End If
Next
...
```

I can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21728694/how-to-access-custom-layout-slides-through-vba#21733323) that I can reference the layout master slide, but I cannot find how to export it. Phind thinks I can create a blank slide using the master and then export it that way, but it doesn't seem to like it.

As an extra challenge - I realised I am running Powerpoint 2016! :)

Comment: I can't answer your question but I'm intrigued as to how you export a slide (or shapes on it) to .PNG with VBA. I have a use case.

Comment: Why do you want/need extracting the master slides **as picture (PNG**? You can export it as template and then, import it in another presentation...

Comment: I'm translating the pptx to LaTex

Comment: I'd  you should be able to reproduce shapes and text formatting in LaTex, recreating the content of a slide.

Comment: @OranG.Utan  Sure, but try that with a slide that might include a table, a chart, smartart, images and whatever else the user might have added to it.

Comment: exactly Steve.. worse still Powerpoint design slides have a grab bag of pictures, drawings and the like - yes I could copy it by hand - but I want to do something quickly instead in years.. To make it worse a lot of things are parent-child relationships, so a text box might have text and pictures within it..

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
Sub ExportMasterSlidesToPNG()
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim masterSlide As master
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 1 ' Counter for exported PNG files
    
    ' Loop through all slides in the presentation
    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        ' Check if the slide is a master slide
        If sld.Master Is Nothing Then
            ' Slide is not a master slide; do nothing
        Else
            ' Slide is a master slide; export it as a PNG
            Set masterSlide = sld.Master
            masterSlide.Copy
            With New Presentation
                .Slides.Paste
                .SaveAs "C:\Path\To\Export\Location\MasterSlide_" & i & ".png", ppSaveAsPNG
                .Close
            End With
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next sld
End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't even compile. And in all likelihood, OP wants to extract images of each Layout. Your current code will return a reference to the master for each slide (in most cases, the same thing for each) rather than to the layout that actually controls the appearance of the slide.

Answer (score 0):

Start a new presentation based on the theme/template you want to work with then run this to add new blank slides, one for each master and layout in the presentation.

You can then use a simple loop through the slides and call the .Export method on each of them to make your PNGs, named however you like, at pretty much whatever resolution you need.

```
Sub MakeMasterSlidesForExport()

Dim oDes As Design
Dim oLay As CustomLayout
Dim lDesCount As Long
Dim lLayCount As Long

With ActivePresentation
    For lDesCount = 1 To .Designs.Count
        For lLayCount = 1 To .Designs(lDesCount).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts.Count
            .Slides.AddSlide .Slides.Count, .Designs(lDesCount).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(lLayCount)
        Next
    Next
End With

End Sub
```